# Prove $\mathbb{Z}_4\ncong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Question: How can I show $\mathbb{Z}_4\ncong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$  without considering index (order of elements), without using cyclic argument or using Sylow's theorem?

Is there a way to do it? I usually try to prove something is isomorphic to another thing, so I'm kinda lost trying to prove the opposite. And I thought about the two ways bellow but they didn't help me much.

Both of them are commutative and have the same cardinality ($\mathbb{Z}_4 =\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{3}\} \implies \#\mathbb{Z}_4 =4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 =\{(\overline{0},\overline{0}),(\overline{0},\overline{1}),(\overline{1},\overline{0}),(\overline{1},\overline{1})\} \implies \#(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2) =4$).

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Why don't you want to consider orders of elements ? (I am always a bit startled about questions like "how to prove that without using anything that can help")

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I officially don't know these things yet (I'm in the begging of the course :/), so I can't use them to solve my question. This is the last thing I need to solve it entirely.

Comment: Well you can say that in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, every element satisfies $x + x = 0$, but this is not the case in $\mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: $\math Z_4$ has an element of order 4.  That's by definition.  If $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ then $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and $a^2, b^2 = 0$ and $(a,b)^2 = 0$ so no element of $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ has order $4$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb Z_4 \to \mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2$ be a group morphism, with $f(1)=x$. Then $f(2)=f(1)+f(1)=x+x=0=f(0)$, whence $f$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, @Desperado!!